# How can I access a non-final variable in a Thread lambda?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, lambda, final

I have a custom object that I need to modify inside a Thread lambda, as I need to perform an operation and assign some value to it.

The problem is that when I declare the variable in the Thread(), it cannot be returned from the enclosing function. Then, if I try to make it a global variable and assign some value to it inside the Thread, it can't be done because lambdas only allow final or effectively final variables inside them.

What can be a workaround/solution for this?

```
 // Gives an undesired result 
 public class MeClass {
    public static Response response = new Response();

    // TODO: Make response specific to a method and not global

    public Response get(String endpoint) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                this.response = OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.response.isException = true;
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }).start();
        return this.response;
    }
    // Another method with similar function accessing response

}
```

So I want to declare the `response` inside the method itself, but I can't do it due to only final variables being available.

```
// Gives an error
public Response get(String endpoint) {
        Response response = new Response();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                response = OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.response.isException = true;
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }).start();
        return response;
```

Comment: I would go for [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

Comment: Even if the code would compile, it still wouldn't work, because the `return response;` statement executes before the `response = ...;` statement of the thread. **Rethink** what you're trying to do, i.e. why are you creating a thread to run the code in the background, but still expecting the result to instantly available? That makes no sense, now does it?

Comment: I am willing to wait till the process on the separate Thread is complete. But then how should I decalre the response such that I can modify it on the separate Thread and return it's value?

Comment: If you are willing to wait for completion, what’s the point of starting a new thread?

Comment: I am trying to use this in Android, if I don't spin up a new Thread, the UI might freeze. Also I'm trying to generalize this a solution.

Comment: Re, "...Android...UI might freeze..." The only thing that "freezes" the UI is if some function  that is called in the UI thread takes too much time. If a direct call to `makeGetRequest(endpoint)` is freezing the UI, then that means it takes too much time. You can't fix that by asking some other thread to call it and then _waiting_ for the result. That will only take even _more_ time. You're going to have to find some way for your UI to show that you have _started_ the `makeGetRequest(...)` call _now_, and then _later_ when the result comes back, update the UI again to show it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). OP hasn't told us what the _real_ problem is, and is instead asking us to help implement a _bad_ solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this was allowed? What would you expect it to return?

```
// Warning! This is an example of what *NOT* to do.
//
public Response get(String endpoint) {
    Response response = new Response();
    new Thread(() -> {
        response = OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);
    }).start();
    return response;
}
```

There's no reason to think that `response = OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);` statement will be executed until before the `return response;` statement. In fact, it probably will *not* be executed until some time later.

What you really want is;

- for your `get(endpoint)` method to return a *mutable* object, and
- a way for a caller to *wait* until a new value has been stored into the mutable object by some other thread.

The Java standard library defines an interface for just that kind of mutable object: It's called [`java.util.concurrent.Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). A `Future` has a `get()` method that will wait, if necessary, until some other thread has *completed* the Future by giving it a value, and then the `get()` will return the value.

The simplest way to use it is through the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
...
public Future<Response> get(String endpoint) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       return OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);
    });
}
```

A call to this `get(endpoint)` method will submit a task to a built-in thread pool that will execute the given lambda expression, and then it will return a `Future` that will be completed by the task.

If the lambda produces a value, then that will become the value of the `Future`. If the lambda throws an exception, then that will be caught and, and the exception object will be stored in the `Future`

The caller of `get(endpoint)` can do this:

```
...
Future<Response> fr = myClassInstance.get(endpoint);
doSomethingElseConcurrentlyWithThe_makeGetRequest_call(...);
try {
    Response r = fr.get();
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    o.response.isException = true;
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can I make a method in the class itself, that executes

`public Future<Response> get(String endpoint) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       return OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint);
    });
}
`
 and gets the response and returns that response. In turn, I'll call this new method from the actual caller, and the get the response, with no need to have `Future` object in the actual caller?

Comment: @nietzsche, I don't understand why you would want to do that. If the caller never does anything else while it's awaiting the result of `OffredUtil.makeGetRequest(endpoint)`, then what would be the point of doing that in a different thread? Why not simply call that function?

Comment: I basically only want the actual caller to ever access my class, without having to explicitly use `java.util.concurrent` objects like `Future`. Will that work though?

Comment: @nietzsche, What does "work" mean? Do you mean, will the Java compiler let you do it? Yes, the compiler will let you do it. Do you mean, will the caller get the expected result? Yes, the caller will get the expected result. Do you mean will the caller get the expected result in time to prevent your Android UI from freezing? Then No, it won't help with that at all.